# Multiple async image requests & assignments to NSArray

Tags: ios, xcode, asynchronous, uiimage

I struggling to get my head around what should be a very simple problem, fingers crossed someone will be able to identify my mistake or suggest a better approach.

What I'm trying to do is retrieve a number of URL's from an array, and then for each entry start an async image request. These requests will return a UIView object and I'm then adding these to another array for use later in the app.

It's not working and I'm guessing my problem relates to the way the loop is initialising the AsyncImageView, the assignment to the new array and then further initialisations.

```
for (iccAssociatedMediaObject *media in self.mediaArray) {
    if ( [media.usage isEqualToString:@"360"]) {

        // >> Here we have the array entry we need this is a URL string
        NSLog(@"URL : %@", media.href);

        // >> Next I start an Async load of the images, a UIView is returned/created...
        HJManagedImageV *asyncImageView = [[HJManagedImageV alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 620, 620)];
        [asyncImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [asyncImageView showLoadingWheel];
        [asyncImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        [asyncImageView.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        asyncImageView.url = [NSURL URLWithString:media.href];
        // asyncImageView.callbackOnSetImage = (id)self;

        // >> Next I add the UIView (asyncImageView) to an array for use later in the app
        [objMan manage:asyncImageView];

        // >> I think my problem relates to the HJManagedImageV initialization & reuse?????
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not allocate it outside the For-In loop and then just re-use and reset it each pass through the loop?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the issue I was experiencing was due to the project having multiple instances of HJCache.